# redirecting to log inpage in the case of sqltime out exception

Tags: sql, timeoutexception

i have developed a web application with asp.net and c#.net and i use sql server DB,

i am getting sql time out exception occasionally, i want to redirect to the loginpage in the case of sqltimeout exception? how can that be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the database call in a try/catch. If it times out, use the `Response.Redirect()` command.